# General insert function

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET and one of the functions I wrote is below.
The idea behind it is to just send a dictionary and table name to the function, get the result and then return.

Is this good practice or just silly?

```
Public Function dbInsert(ByRef EntryDetails As Dictionary(Of String, String),ByRef table as String) As Integer
    Dim command As new SqlCeCommand

    ' Loop over entries.
    Dim fieldNames() As String = {}
    Dim fieldsValues() As String = {}
    Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
    For Each pair In EntryDetails
        ReDim Preserve fieldNames(0 To UBound(fieldNames) + 1)
        fieldNames(UBound(fieldNames)) = pair.Key
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pair.Key, pair.Value)
    Next

    command = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO "+table+" (" + String.Join(",", fieldNames) + ")", connection.DbPublic)

    Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0
    Try
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn)
        newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        'Console.WriteLine("added: {0}", newProdID)
        Return newProdID
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to insert: {0}", e.Message)
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Using `byref` parameters when not needed is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

> This approach is not much good, but may be suit your required functionality. The method name is dbInsert and you
>   are passing table and data in dictionary. you can make it much better by using better naming convention and parameter types.

On the place of this create a method with following parameter as:
`GetIdentityOnInsert(string sqlQuery, CommandType commandType, SqlParameterCollection sqlParameters)`

query will be: `query = "Insert into tableName value(@param1,@param2);SELECT @@IDENTITY;`"

---

```
Public Function GetIdentityOnInsert(ByVal sqlQuery as String, ByVal commandType as Commandtype, ByVal sqlParameters as SqlParameterCollection)            
Try
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        ' Create the command and set its properties.
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandText = sqlQuery
        command.CommandType = commandType
        Dim parameter As New SqlParameter()

        For Each parameter In sqlParameters            
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        Next      

        ' Open the connection and execute the reader.
        connection.Open()
        Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0
        ' try ExecuteScalar() if it gives error then replace it to ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' and replace the below code as in your question.
        newProdID = command.ExecuteScalar() 

            'Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn)
            'newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            'Console.WriteLine("added: {0}", newProdID)
         Return newProdID

End Using
Catch e As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to insert: {0}", e.Message)
    Return 0
End Try
End Function
```

Hope this help you to create you Data Access Layer. you can extend `ExecuteNonQuery` with the above method.. just you have to customize little bit..

Comment: that functionality doesn't work on Compact Edition 3.5

Comment: why not.. it works same as i explored through these links: [link1](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/29/inserting-rows-into-a-sql-server-compact-edition-table-in-c/), [link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/198722/How-to-use-INSERT-statement-in-SQL-server-compact), [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633.aspx). this should work well..